# How can I append these entries to the list?

Tags: python, recursion

I have written a pair of methods in python:

1. `number_combinations()` which obtains all possible combinations of 3 numbers
2. `checkAllValuesAreDifferent()` which checks that all the values in the list are different

-

```
temp = []

def number_combinations(listOfElements,index):

    if index==3:
        #if checkAllValuesAreDifferent(listOfElements):
        #print "Going to append the following list to the sat tuple list "      
        print listOfElements

        #print "Temp is ",temp

        temp.append(listOfElements)
        print "Temp is ",temp
        print "exit from function " 
        return listOfElements

    else:
        for value in range(3):
            listOfElements[index]=value
            #print "LIST OF ELEMENTS IS ",listOfElements
            if checkAllValuesAreDifferent(listOfElements,index,value)==True:
                #print "RECURSIVE CALL "                
                (number_combinations(listOfElements,index+1))
                #print "THE LIST IS ",temp
                #print "APPENDING TO SAT TUPLES "               
                #print "BACKTRACK HAPPEND ",listOfElements
                #print "AND INDEX IS ",index        

                 #recursive call to next level              

        return #backtrack since no number found

def checkAllValuesAreDifferent(list_of,index,value):

    if index==0:
        return True
    else:
        for i in range(index):
            #print "Entered loop with index ",index
            if(list_of[i]==value):
                return False
        return True
```

When I just try printing the listOfElements, I get the right answer i.e all sets of 3 digits with each distinct. However, when I try appending to the list temp, I end up getting duplicate entries. So temp should be : `[0,1,2],[0,2,1][1,0,2][1,2,0][2,0,1][2,1,0]`
(which is the result of printing alone).However,temp turns out to be `[[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]]`

I cannot figure out the problem with this. Could anyone give me some idea as to how to successfully append the right lists being generated to the temp list.

Comment: [... Seriously?](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams -- using that method would be preferable, yeah, since it exists in the stdlib, but writing one by yourself is good exercise. There's also a very valuable lesson to be learned about mutable and immutable types in Python here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are passing the same `listOfElements` back to the function, and it will be modified in place.

You can use the `[:]` idiom to shallow-copy a list:

```
temp.append(listOfElements[:])
```

Comment: Thanks.I made the change and it worked but could you please clarify what you mean. I am passing the same listOfElements back to the function but shouldn't it be appended to the next position? Also shouldn't it only be appended when the base case is reached? In the base case listOfElements never becomes [2 2 2] so why is this happening?